# Access handlebars array using index of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars.js to iterate over `categories`, and then use the current array index to access an element in the `series` array.  I am able to do so using the below helper.

```
var json={
    "categories": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "category 0"
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "category 1"
        }
    ],
    "series": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "DUMMY",
            "data": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "series 0 data 0"
                }, {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "series 0 data 1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Handlebars.registerHelper('getArrayValues', function(ar, index, prop) {
    return ar[0].data[index][prop];
});

var template = Handlebars.compile(json);

{{#each categories}}
<p>id: {{this.id}}</p>
<p>name: {{this.name}}</p>
<p>series id with helper: {{getArrayValues ../series @index 'id' }}</p>
<p>series name with helper: {{getArrayValues ../series @index 'name' }}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Am I able to do so without a helper?  Below is my attempt.  I've also tried using `lookup`, but can seem to be able to access the properties that `lookup` returns.

```
{{#each categories}}
<p>id: {{this.id}}</p>
<p>name: {{this.name}}</p>
<p>series id: {{../series.[0].data.[@index].id}}</p>
<p>series name: {{../series.[0].data.[@index].name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I founded for this, I do not know how much good it is but It is working perfectly

Try this :)

```
{{#each categories}}
  <p>id: {{this.id}}</p>
  <p>name: {{this.name}}</p>
  <p>series id with helper:{{#with (lookup  ../series.[0].data 
  @index) }}{{this.id}}{{/with}}</p>
  <p>series name with helper: {{#with (lookup  ../series.[0].data 
  @index) }}{{this.name}}{{/with}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant,  While I am sure your answer is accurate (however, haven't tested),  maybe I will stick with my silly helper function as it makes sense to me.  Edit.  Probably will change to yours.

Comment: Tested, and works perfect.  I found `#with` documentation at https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html.  Thanks

Comment: Can you please suggest what to do when series can also be an array of object. I tried this ```{{#with (lookup  ../series.[@index].data 
@index) }}{{this.id}}{{/with}}``` but it doesn't work.